# WPF ListView with Checkboxes unchecks

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, checkbox

I have a `ListView` with checkboxes. But sometimes, when I check a checkbox all others checkboxes checked earlier get unchecked. I can't find, where is the problem.

Will be grateful for any help.

Here is XAML code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SeatCars}" SelectionChanged="SeatSelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"></CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here is EventHandler:

```
private void SeatSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
    {
        MainViewModel.SeatSelected.Add(item.ToString());
    }
    foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
    {
        MainViewModel.SeatSelected.Remove(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

But the problem persists even without the eventhandler.

Comment: Does **SeatCars** content remain the same? Is it ObservableCollection? I have tried some small app. but don't seem to be able to reproduce your problem so maybe something is missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of your IsChecked value ...

Here is My Checkbox Design which may help you .

```
 <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxZone" Content="{Binding TheText}" 
                                  Tag="{Binding TheValue}"    
                                    Margin="0,5,0,0"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChkBox1Checked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  Command="{Binding DataContext.OnCheckedCommand,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel} }}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CheckBoxZone, Path=Tag}">
```

Comment: it was due to Ischecked. Thanks for your help.